# Download or view uploaded file located in the serverb yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have uploaded  a file to the server and I would like to download the file. How should I do that .

This is the upload  in the controller

```
    {
        $model = new Upload();  
       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {
                $filename = $model->_upload;
                $model->_upload= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'_upload');
                $model->_upload->saveAs('uploads/'.$filename.'.'.$model->_upload->extension);
                $model->_upload = 'uploads/'.$filename.'.'.$model->_upload->extension;
                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_uploads]);




                    return $this->redirect(['index']);

        }
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,

        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `uploads` folder is in the web directory or webroot, you can use the below function, just copy paste into your controller and then to download the file, type the url along with the `filename` in the query string like for instance if your controller name is `FilesController` then the url will be `www.mydomain.com/files/download?filename=your_file_name`

```
 /**
 * Downloads the file
 *
 * @param string $filename the name of the file to be downloaded
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDownload($filename)
{
    $filepath = \Yii::getalias('@webroot') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($filepath);
}
```

### Pay Attention

- It is the simplest way to do it you are saving the file name along with the path in the table which is wrong, you should just save the file name along with the extension like `my_file.doc` without path, and then to download the file just lookup the filename in the table using the file id rather than the filename or any kind of hash that you store along with the filename in the table

  ```
  public function actionDownload($fileId)
  {
         $filename = Upload::findOne(['id_uploads'=>$fileId]);
         $filepath = \Yii::getalias('@webroot') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
             . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
         return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($filepath);
  }
  ```
- Secondly you should follow naming conventions for the class properties, `_upload` for a public property looks odd as mostly private member variables are prefixed with an underscore. you should use some coding standards like [phpcs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)
- and what is with the 2 redirect statements inside the `if` condition

  ```
  return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_uploads]);
  return $this->redirect(['index']);
  ```

  the second one is unreachable just remove it.

Comment: Missing required parameters: filename

Comment: I have tried this but its not working                                                             ```public function actionDownload()
    {
        $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') .'/uploads';
        $file = $path.'/test.docx';
       //print_r($file);exit;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            Yii::$app->response->xSendFile($file);
            //Yii::$app->session->setFlash('Success','Successs');
        }else {
            echo 'The file does not exist';
        }
    }```      In the view file  ```<td><?php echo Html::a('Download',['/contracts/download']); ?></td>```

Comment: i cant get anything you have pasted in the comment section please use the question and add the details in your question by editing and are you using the top part of the code suggested or the later one? @rabin254

Comment: and you should really pay attention rather than copy-pasting the code, you wont be able to work on your own like this, the exception `Missing required parameters: filename` is a default exception raised by the controller action because you are not passing the `filename` to the action which takes the `filename` as a parameter as it is defined `actionDownload($filename)`, you need to pass the filename via the anchor link you are using your link should look like this `<td><?php echo Html::a('Download',['/contracts/download','filename'=>'test.docx']); ?></td>` @rabin254

Comment: I got you right..When I download the file and open it, its empty. How can I solve that

Comment: not sure about why , but most of the times its the path that is wrong in this case, also check if the file has sufficient rights @rabin254